# Ajax call wait till is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, ready

I can't seem to figure this out. I have an Ajax call with Jquery and when the server response is done is have an element reloaded like this `$('#test').load(document.URL +  ' #test');`.

Display property of the element's style is set to none. After the response is done I would like to refresh the element and when that is done than show that element.

when I try this

```
.done(function() {
  $('#test').load(document.URL +  ' #test');
  $('#test').show();
});
```

The element will show but the refresh is not done so it will hide after a second.

I aslo tried to put it in a variable and call the ready function on the variable like this:

```
.done(function() {
  var ready = $('#test').load(document.URL +  ' #test');
  $(ready).ready(function() {
    $('#test').show();
  });
});
```

Also not working.

How can I let show() wait till the previous line of code is ready?

THNX!

Comment: use the call back... see the load() documentation. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Have you tried adding the `complete: function(){}` event listener? I don't use jQuery much so I'm not sure if `complete:` will be the equivalent to a call back.

Comment: Curious why your initial ajax doesn't return the data needed instead of making 2 ajax calls since `load()` is also an ajax call

Comment: @NewToJS no, `load()` has a callback argument as per docs

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, wasn't too sure as I don't really bother with `jQuery`. I will remember this if I ever find myself using `jQuery`'s ajax. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.load`'s callback like below:

```
....
     $('#test').load(document.URL +  ' #test', function(){
            //PAGE LOADED
             $('#test').show();
     });

....
```

Comment: Thnx! Worked for me!

Comment: @Scandeep can you help me to find out the solution for this Q [Question  LINK___](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450997/jquery-load-function-not-work-proper-way-when-i-am-using-multi)